# Is either the whisper.sh messaging app or the "Open Whisper Systems" project related to the Ethereum whisper project?

Tags: whisper, shh

There is the Whisper "anonymous messaging app", described in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whisper_%28app%29).

And then there is also something called "Open Whisper Systems", described in [this other Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Whisper_Systems).

Is either one of these somehow related to the Ethereum "whisper" messaging project, or are they completely separate things?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two are related in name, and perhaps in their goals. Whisper.sh was released in 2012 and is operated and controlled by a single entity. Ethereum's Whisper protocol is peer to peer and is not controlled by a single entity. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BrWlAtfqF6s) is a link to a YouTube presentation by Dr Gavin Wood about Ethereum's Whisper.

Comment: Thanks @InternetOfMe, I had also updated the question about the "Open Whisper Systems" project. I guess this is not related to the Ethereum's Whisper protocol either(?)

Comment: It doesn't look like it to me. It is quite a coincidence with regards to the naming and goals of the project though.

Comment: It's absolutely not related except on the idea of messaging.